# Select statement with where clause in C#

Tags: c#, sql

How to write a select statement with where clause.i need to compare with a string value.

I tried this:

```
string get_dropdown_value = dropdown_category.SelectedItem.Value;
```

...but it gives me this error:

```
Invalid column name 'get_dropdown_value'.
```

Comment: You will have to show a little bit more code than that, is this select to a database? Which version/RDBMS? What is the select statement look like? What does the table schema look like.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to show the select statement you are using. I suspect you have done something like this:

```
string selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_COLUMN = get_dropdown_value";
```

While it should be like:

```
string selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_COLUMN = " + get_dropdown_value;
```

Edit: As others mentioned, this is prone to SQL Injection. So, you might want to use SqlParamter (assuming you are using SQL).

Comment: SQL Injection. Wide, wide open to SQL Injection. Use Parameterized Queries rather.

Comment: You might want to amend this answer to use commands and parameters so you can avoid SQL injection attacks: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Dan +1 for that xkcd. I should have pointed this out in original post itself. :doh:

Comment: it is working now.But suppose i select a MVC value from dropdownlist then cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); is giving the following error.
Invalid column name 'MVC3'.
why?

Comment: What is MVC value? Are you referring to web application that uses MVC? If yes, then please please do not use the query. Make it secure. Give us some more information here, preferably by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

insted of

```
string get_dropdown_value = dropdown_category.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Put

```
string get_dropdown_value = dropdown_category.SelectedItem.Text;
```